# Web pages show empty band across the top

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

In Chrome, site http://www.helpinghandspeople.com has a 16px empty band (background colour shows) across the top of the page.

It's not supposed to be there, but I can't figure out how to make it go away. In Firefox, the home page shows fine, but login and a few other pages show a 24px band.

Viewing source and running inspect element are not helpful.

Does anyone have a suggestion where to look?

Thanks

Gerry

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm supposed to be looking for. Maybe give a little bit more description where this band you're referring to is.

Comment: you have malformed HTML. Run it through an HTML validator. You forgot to close an element properly.

Comment: @Radagaisus: you're right and after correcting that, I am still no further.
The UTF-8 devil keeps hounding me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run your source through an HTML validator?  On the login page it looks like you are missing a closing tag for `<div id="topSectionWWW">`.

Comment: However, on the home page there is my old UTF-8 error. I just can't seem to get rid of that.
It's the only error, and the empty band is still there, so I guess that is the problem.
Now how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure about that one.  Chrome does show a high unicode character _ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)_ just above the first meta tag.  Run with that.

Answer (score 1):

looks like u have a space somewhere thats causing it,

after the `<div style="padding-bottom: 50px; padding-right: 50px; display: none; " id="colorbox" class="">` div

also, you have head tags inside your body

you should move the `<meta> <title>` and `<link>` tags to the head

Comment: ...as well as all the script tags, unless there's some reason they REALLY need to be in the `<body>` instead.

Comment: That is the browser's interpretation. I put that stuff in the <head> section.

Comment: @ETWW-Dave script tags actually can be in the body, and its generally a better idea to put them at the base of your body if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have some sort of hidden character occurring before your doctype. The fact that the browser is rendering empty space in the `body` element, along with elements that are supposed to be in the document `head` (`meta` tags, `title` tag), I think can be explained by this.

[image]

In this screenshot you can see the space that's causing the problem, but as I say I think the space actually occurs *before* your doctype is declared.

Comment: Jonathan, it seems to be a utf-8 multi-byte character, and the metatags are in the header.
If you run http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.helpinghandspeople.com and show source, you will see that I am outputting the meta tags and links in the head section.
You will also see that it says _Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File_ and I have no idea how it gets in there or how to get rid of it...